# Django. Increment views count of object without affecting its updated_at field

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
```

my view:

```
class AnnouncementDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Announcement
    context_object_name = 'announcement'
    template_name = 'web/index.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        announcement = get_object_or_404(Announcement, id=kwargs['id'])
        announcement.views += 1
        announcement.save()
        return super().get(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problems are:

1. I know about the **F** expression, I'll use it down below, but I want to know another ways of updating field and not updating the **updated_at** field.
2. I want to save the changes of model's `views` field but everytime I save it, it sets the new value to `updated_at` field. It means everytime I refresh the page it shows the current time on **updated_at** field, which is very bad.

I have changed my view's code to:

```
...
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Announcement.objects.filter(id=kwargs['id']).update(views=F('views') + 1)
    return super().get(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now it works fine but I have several questions. How it saves the new value of `views` field without calling the **save** method of """"Django"""""? How far can I go with it. What is the best practices of changing some fields of model without hitting the **save** method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this, might be to specify `update_fields` in the [**`.save(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save):

```
class AnnouncementDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Announcement
    context_object_name = 'announcement'
    template_name = 'web/index.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().get(self, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            object = getattr(self, 'object', None)
            if object:
                object.views = F('views') + 1
                object.save(update_fields=('views',))
```

It is however better to work with an `F`-expression to avoid *race-conditions*.

Making use of:

```
Announcement.objects.filter(id=kwargs['id']).update(views=F('views') + 1)
```

will let the database make a query that looks like:

```
UPDATE appname_announcement
SET view = view + 1
WHERE id = id
```

If you thus do not have to load the object in memory, this will be more efficient, since it makes a single roundtrip to the database.